# Autocomplete implementation in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, binary-search, trie, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete implementation in Python, and it passed all of the unit tests that I have included at the bottom.

```
#!python

import random
import time


def get_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        words_list = f.read().split()
    return words_list
    print(words_list)


def binarysearch(list_, item, left=None, right=None):
    if left is None and right is None:
        left = 0
        right = len(list_) - 1
    middle = (right + left) // 2
    item_length = len(item)
    middle_item = list_[middle]
    if middle_item[:item_length].lower() == item.lower():
        return find_all_words(list_, item, middle)
    elif middle_item[:item_length].lower() < item.lower():
        return binarysearch(list_, item, middle + 1, right)
    elif middle_item[:item_length].lower() > item.lower():
        return binarysearch(list_, item, left, middle - 1)
    elif left > right:
        return None


def find_all_words(list_, item, middle):
    predicted_words = [list_[middle]]
    item_length = len(item)
    left_match = True
    right_match = False
    left_index = middle
    right_index = middle
    while left_match:
        left_index -= 1
        if left_index < 0:
            left_match = False
        else:
            word = list_[left_index]
            if word[:item_length] == item:
                predicted_words.append(word)
            else:
                left_match = False
    while right_match:
        right_index += 1
        if right_index >= len(list_):
            right_match = False
        else:
            word = list_[right_index]
            if word[:item_length] == item:
                predicted_words.append(word)
            else:
                right_match = False
    return predicted_words

def autocomplete(prefix=""):
    filename = "/usr/share/dict/words"
    words_list = get_words(filename)
    predicted_words = binarysearch(words_list, prefix)
    return predicted_words

def benchmark(all_prefixes):
    t1 = time.time()
    for prefix in all_prefixes:
        autocomplete(prefix)
    t2 = time.time()
    return t2 - t1


def main():
    all_words = get_words('/usr/share/dict/words')
    all_prefixes = set([word[:len(word)//2] for word in all_words])
    time = benchmark(all_prefixes)
    print('Took {} seconds to benchmark {} prefixes on {} words'.format(time, len(all_prefixes), len(all_words)))
    # import sys
    # prefix = sys.argv[1]
    # words = autocomplete(prefix)
    # print(words)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# autocomplete_test.py


#!python

from autocomplete import insert_word
from tries import Trie
import unittest


class TrieTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_init(self):
        trie = Trie()
        data, is_word = trie.root.data
        assert data == ""
        assert is_word is False
        assert trie.root.next == {}

    def test_insert_with_3_items(self):
        trie = Trie()
        assert trie.root.data == ('', False)
        assert trie.root.next == {}
        trie.insert("a")
        assert trie.root.next['a'] is not None
        assert len(trie.root.next) == 1
        node = trie.root.next['a']
        assert node.data == ('a', True)
        assert node.next == {}
        trie.insert("a")
        assert trie.root.next['a'] is not None
        assert len(trie.root.next) == 1
        node = trie.root.next['a']
        assert node.data == ('a', True)
        assert node.next == {}
        trie.insert("b")
        assert trie.root.next['b'] is not None
        assert len(trie.root.next) == 2
        node = trie.root.next['b']
        assert node.data == ('b', True)
        assert node.next == {}
        trie.insert("c")
        assert trie.root.next['c'] is not None
        assert len(trie.root.next) == 3
        node = trie.root.next['c']
        assert node.data == ('c', True)
        assert node.next == {}

    def test_inset_with_7_items(self):
        trie = Trie()
        words_list = ['a', 'app', 'apple', 'be', 'bee', 'beat', 'c']
        for word in words_list:
            trie.insert(word)
        assert trie.root.data == ('', False)
        assert len(trie.root.next) == 3

        assert trie.root.next['a'] is not None
        node = trie.root.next['a']
        assert node.data == ('a', True)
        assert len(node.next) == 1
        assert node.next['p'] is not None
        node = node.next['p']
        assert node.data == ('ap', False)
        assert len(node.next) == 1
        assert node.next['p'] is not None
        node = node.next['p']
        assert node.data == ('app', True)
        assert len(node.next) == 1
        assert node.next['l'] is not None
        node = node.next['l']
        assert node.data == ('appl', False)
        assert len(node.next) == 1
        assert node.next['e'] is not None
        node = node.next['e']
        assert node.data == ('apple', True)
        assert len(node.next) == 0

        assert trie.root.next['b'] is not None
        node = trie.root.next['b']
        assert node.data == ('b', False)
        assert len(node.next) == 1
        assert node.next['e'] is not None
        node = node.next['e']
        assert node.data == ('be', True)
        assert len(node.next) == 2
        assert node.next['e'] is not None
        node1 = node.next['e']
        assert node1.data == ('bee', True)
        assert len(node1.next) == 0
        assert node.next['a'] is not None
        node2 = node.next['a']
        assert node2.data == ('bea', False)
        assert len(node2.next) == 1
        assert node2.next['t'] is not None
        node = node2.next['t']
        assert node.data == ('beat', True)
        assert len(node.next) == 0

        assert trie.root.next['c'] is not None
        node = trie.root.next['c']
        assert node.data == ('c', True)
        assert len(node.next) == 0


class AutocompleteTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_insert_word():
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to have used the `random` module, so that import can be deleted. In your first function `get_words()`, you have put a `print(words_list)` immediately after an unconditional return, which is unreachable. Unless this is for debugging, it is best to either put it before the return statement or delete it altogether.

---

`binarysearch` is composed of two words, and should be separated with an underscore for consistency. The conditional for the first `if` statement is a bit redundant, since whenever one index is `None`, the other must also be the same. If you do want to check both, you should probably use an `or` rather than `and`, since *neither* is allowed to be `None`.

The final `elif` of the function is again unreachable, this time because one of the previous comparisons (`==`, `<`, `>`) will **always** be true. This implementation means your binary search will never terminate correctly if the search term is not present in the dictionary — instead, check if the search should terminate at the **beginning** of the function.

You can also do the slicing and lowercasing of your variables immediately instead of repeating for each `if` statement.

```
def binary_search(list_, item, left=None, right=None):
    if left is None or right is None:
        left = 0
        right = len(list_) - 1
    elif left > right:
        return None
    item = item.lower()
    middle = (right + left) // 2
    sliced_middle_item = list_[middle][:len(item)].lower()
    if sliced_middle_item == item:
        return find_all_words(list_, item, middle)
    if sliced_middle_item < item:
        return binary_search(list_, item, middle + 1, right)
    if sliced_middle_item > item:
        return binary_search(list_, item, left, middle - 1)
```

Since this is a single branch problem and Python does not optimise tail calls, it may be more efficent to impement your binary search iteratively using a loop instead of recursively.

```
def binary_search(list_, item):
    left = 0
    right = len(list_) - 1
    item = item.lower()
    while True:
        if left > right:
            return None
        middle = (left + right) // 2
        sliced_middle_item = list_[middle][:len(item)]
        if sliced_middle_item < item:
            left = middle + 1
        elif sliced_middle_item > item:
            right = middle - 1
        elif sliced_middle_item == item:
            return find_all_words(list_, item, middle)
```

---

In `find_all_words`, you have initialized `right_match` to `False`, which means the second loop will never run, and you will not find any values to the right of the first match. Also, using a flag variable that controls the loop is really no different from using a `break` statement, except you won't need to put the second half of your loop in an `else` block.

Instead of building your list one at a time using `.append()`, it is probably more efficent to find the first match and last match and then using the indcies to slice the word list. As a bonus this will also maintain the lexical ordering of the list. This will also mean you can use a binary search to find the first and last matches instead of a linear search. It would be best to continue from the previous search rather than starting from scratch, taking `left` and `right` as parameters as well.

```
def binary_find_all(list_, item, left, middle, right):
    half_right = middle
    half_left = middle
    while left < half_right:
        middle = (left + half_right) // 2
        sliced_middle_item = list_[middle][:len(item)]
        if sliced_middle_item < item:
            left = middle + 1
        else:
            half_right = middle
    while half_left < right:
        middle = (half_left + right) // 2
        sliced_middle_item = list_[middle][:len(item)]
        if sliced_middle_item == item:
            half_left = middle + 1
        else:
            right = middle
    return list_[left:right]
```

---

It is really unnessary and inefficent to reopen the file and reset the word list for every invocation of `autocomplete()` — on my machine, 1000 invocations of the binary search takes around 60 ms for most search terms, while 1000 invocations of `autocomplete()` as it is written would take over 30 seconds: 500 times slower! Just delete it, or make it an alias of `binary_search()` if you have to.

---

For your unit tests, I think your tests for the above code has been cut off, either by the site or during cutting and pasting. I only see the tests for the Trie data type. I'm not sure why you're testing it, or why you haven't used it in your main code, but the tests themselves look fine.

Comment: i don't think I miss any unit testings of my file. you can find my file here at github

Comment: @NinjaG, I'm afraid that I am unable to find any public repository of gist containing what appears to be your autocomplete linked to the GitHub username in your profile (Jeffchiucp). Nor can I see any code in the class AutocompleteTest, except the line `def test_insert_word():` with nothing in the function. I think one more thing I forgot to mention is that, depending on use case, it might be a good idea to add docstrings to your functions. Also, binary search might return `[]` instead of `None`. I'll edit it in only when there's something else significant to add though.